# How can I configure Spring Security 6 to ignore the static resources folder?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am storing my public web resources (CSS, JS) in the 'static' folder, with the following path: 'java/com/myapp/resources/static/**'. Here my configuration classes:

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() throws Exception {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/static/**");
    }

}
```

And ResourceConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) { 
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
    
}
```

It worked on Spring Security version 5.x.x, but in the current version of Spring Security (which is 6.0.3), the method 'antMatchers(String)' is undefined for the type 'WebSecurity.IgnoredRequestConfigurer', so I can't configure it in the same way anymore.

I read this document (**https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-requestmatchers**) which stated that I can replace the deprecated 'antMatchers' methods with 'requestMatchers', like so:

```java
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/resources/static/**");
}
```

However, even after making this change, my CSS files are still missing. So, I would like to ask: how can I configure Spring Security 6 to ignore the static resources folder? Thank you.

Comment: The `resources/static` folder structure is the default in Spring Boot, with `com.myapp` being my package. The `ResourceConfig` class has no problems because I can load the CSS files when I put them there without Spring Security. However, I don't know how to make Spring Security 6 ignore the 'static' folder. When I set it to `/**`, the CSS files load, but neither `/static/` nor `classpath:/static/**` or `/resources/static/**` seem to work.

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem now. I should ignore the folder inside the 'static' folder, not the 'static' folder itself  `return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/css/**");`. Thank @dur

Answer (score 0):

It’s more secure because even with static resources it’s important to write secure headers, which Spring Security cannot do if the request is ignored.

In this past, this came with a performance tradeoff since the session was consulted by Spring Security on every request. As of Spring Security 6, however, the session is no longer pinged unless required by the authorization rule. Because the performance impact is now addressed, Spring Security recommends using at least permitAll for all requests.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#favor-permitall

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**On requestMatchers add new AntPathRequestMatcher("YOUR PATH"):**

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().
                       requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/**")).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(form ->form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
```

}