Cannot access because HTTP ERROR 403 when using spring boot security to login
Hey guys i'm trying to implement login by using Spring boot security, but i cannot using default username and password defined in application.properties as well as in DB to login. When i hit the button, it direct me to this url: http://localhost:8080/error?continue
I got the HTTP ERROR 403 say that i don't have authorization to view this page.
Here is the code in my SecurityConfig.java
package com.firstweb.web.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder () {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers("/login", "/register", "/clubs", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/clubs?success")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll())
            ;
        return http.build();
    }

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder((passwordEncoder()));
    }

}

Here is my screenshot in browser
I try to go back, login again and it works! I don't know why it always fails at the first time.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097411/how-can-i-configure-spring-security-6-to-ignore-the-static-resources-folder

Show your Spring Security DEBUG logs. Show your requests, for example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser (F12).

/static/js isn't the same as /js. You probably wanted to add /static/** to the list of allowed URLs. No the single /css/** and /js/** because those won't match.
